# Why is my image not displaying ? html

Tags: html, netbeans

Im using netbeans and calling an image on my desktop. This is my code: `<img src ="desktop/SF.jpg" height="300" width="300">` and it is not being displayed! I have tried moving to documents and calling it from there also and still would not work!

Comment: You haven't posted any code :)

Comment: show your code here

Answer (score 1):

Problem in the link of the image referenced, rest of the code is fine. Write the complete absolute address of desktop. for example. C:/Users/xyz/desktop/image.jpeg.

Comment: I'm unsure, but don't you need a leading file:// here?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the extension its `.jpg` or  `.png` also check the its capital letter or small letter (`.JPG`) or   (`.PNG`).

Answer (score 0):

1. Could be the extension .jpg or .jpeg
2. Could b ur folder location. I assume your html file is on the desktop and there's a folder called desktop (also on the desktop) containing your image. The arrangement stated is valid and should work.
   NB: If the image is on the desktop, remove 'desktop/' from your code and finally have 'src=SF.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder and give a name like "myewfolder" and put all your html and css files and also the images inside this newly created folder.

Now update your image code like bellow:

Comment: <img src ="desktop/SF.jpg" height="300" width="300">

Comment: Did not work.. I made a new folder on the desktop and put the image file in it with html project file

Comment: I put it in documents how would i call it from there?

Comment: First of all you make a folder in your desktop and put all the html,css,image in that folder and write this code: <img src ="SF.jpg" height="300" width="300">  and ensure image name and format is same in forlder and code.Remember image name and format is case sensitive